# How can I set footnotes' numbers as superscript in a French report?

Tags: footnotes, report, french

How to make footnotes' numbers take this form? Preferable by `\renewcommand`.

[image]

Here is what I'm getting using this code:

```
\documentclass[%
    ,12pt
    ,french
    ]{report}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
Test\footnote{ojndscosdsncsdpn}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Would you mind being a bit more explicit about what you mean by "this form"? E.g., do you want the footnote numbers to be typeset in a sans-serif font -- and, if so, *which* sans-serif font? Or is that they're supposed to be quite diminutive? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico, I'm just trying to displaying the number as highest as possible like in that snapshot.

Comment: The screenshot you've provided would appear to place the footnote number in the standard superscript position (and size). TeX and LaTeX will do so as well -- unless instructed otherwise. Are you maybe loading one or more packages that affect the appearance of footnote materials? If so, please advise.

Comment: @Mico, I've edited my post.

Comment: I have edited it, too. The MWE can be reduced to the report class with French option in babel. If you take it out, you get a behaviour closer to the one you want. With the clarified question, I hope, an answer will come.

Comment: @Mico, yes changing the footnote size and position is the only thing that I want.

Comment: See my answer, solved it for French report with one new line. But no renewcommand.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, PERFECT! Can you just add a little space between the number and the footnote?

Comment: @user3289501 Why would you want this? The french typographical standard is to typeset footnotes the way `babel` does it. So, I am glad you got your answer, but I would suggest that this is not the best typographic idea for French language (you probably have your reasons, but I am stating this for future reference).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by the French option loaded for the report class or with the package babel. You may switch this behaviour off by adding `\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}` after the loading of `babel`. This will result in the more common superscript style.

Other style corrections such as hang or flushed marginals can be done by the package `footmisc` with its easy to read [documentation](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/footmisc.pdf).

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{report} % report as requested
\usepackage[french]{babel} % French language chosen in babel
\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false} % This line switches off the french footnote style.
% The rest is just cosmetics to get closer to your picture.
\usepackage{fnpct} % Just a cool package for nice footnotes at colons.
\usepackage[%
    ,hang % sets the footnote more to the right (left aligned to the line)
    ,flushmargin % reduces the distance between number and footnote
    ]{footmisc} % See the manual of footnote for custom margins a.s.o.


\begin{document}
This is a test\footnote{ojndscosdsncsdpn}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you please provide an example using `\renewcommand`?

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify. I don't know, what you really want. Vertical rise of the number, vertical rise of everything, horizontal placement, reduced spaces behind the number? It would be just a guess. And have a look on http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc as it provides many solutions already.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: PERFECT! Can you just add a little space between the number and the footnote?

Comment: Just play around with the package options of footmisc. Maybe you like one. The documentation is very easy. Or you just switch it off, maybe, the very default is already beautiful enough.